# Ansys Fluent Unresovled error in UDF

Tags: user-defined-functions, fluent

I am getting:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_RP_Get_Integer referenced in function _update_mc

While using:

```
physical_dt = RP_Get_Integer("physical-time-step");
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some more information what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am working on ansys fluent 13.0.0
I am trying to make a user defined function to update moisture content through the given udf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1KTCZ4AQFjjajhXRHkzZFhHWk0/edit?usp=sharing
and I am having problem with physical_dt = RP_Get_Integer("physical-time-step");
and error is error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_RP_Get_Integer referenced in function _update_mc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use the wrong RP variable macro.
So, to get the physical time step, you can use either:
`physical_dt = RP_Get_Real("physical-time-step");`
or the solver Macro:

`physical_dt = CURRENT_TIMESTEP;`

For more information, refer to [*Ansys Fluent UDF Manual*](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/15.0.7/en-us/help/flu_udf/flu_udf.html) .